# Why don't the any_cast function overloads cause ambiguity?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, boost-any

Boost's `<boost/any.hpp>` has:

```
template<typename ValueType>
ValueType any_cast(any & operand);

template<typename ValueType>
inline ValueType any_cast(const any & operand);
```

(among other variants.) Shouldn't this combination cause ambiguity in calls such as `boost::any_cast<int>(my_any);` ?

I'm asking because if I write this program:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ValueType>
ValueType any_cast(boost::any & operand)
{
        return boost::any_cast<ValueType>(operand);
}

int main()
{
        int x = 123;
        boost::any my_any(x);
        std::cout << "my_any = " << any_cast<int>(my_any) << "\n";
        return 0;
}
```

I do get a [complaint about ambiguity](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a92704976d97b7e):

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:14:57: error: call of overloaded 'any_cast(boost::any&)' is ambiguous
         std::cout << "my_any = " << any_cast<int>(my_any) << "\n";
                                                         ^
main.cpp:5:11: note: candidate: ValueType any_cast(boost::any&) [with ValueType = int]
 ValueType any_cast(boost::any & operand)
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
/usr/local/include/boost/any.hpp:281:22: note: candidate: ValueType boost::any_cast(const boost::any&) [with ValueType = int]
     inline ValueType any_cast(const any & operand)
                      ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/any.hpp:258:15: note: candidate: ValueType boost::any_cast(boost::any&) [with ValueType = int]
     ValueType any_cast(any & operand)
               ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What happens when you replace your global `any_cast` with a simple `using boost::any_cast;`. Does main build?

Answer (score 5):

Why would the calls be ambiguous? The way you call the function the `any` argument is an lvalue. Thus, the `any` argument will either be `const`-qualified in which case the second overload is the only potential match or it is not `const`-qualified in which case the first overload is the better match (there is no conversion needed while the second overload would need a conversion from `any&` to `any const&`). If you call the function with a temporary `any`, it could bind to an rvalue overload (i.e., taking `any&&`) or, if that doesn't exist, it can bind to the `const`-qualified overload but not the non-`const`-qualified overload, again, not causing any ambiguity.

Actually, there is something interesting happening here: without the overload in the global namespace the function using the explicit template argument *cannot* be used! However, as soon as *any* function template is present, even a non-matching one, it *can* be used! Here is an example:

```
namespace foo {
    struct bar {};

    template <typename T> void bar_cast(bar&) {}
    template <typename T> void bar_cast(bar const&) {}
    template <typename T> void bar_cast(bar&&) {}
}

struct whatever;
template <typename T> void bar_cast(whatever);

int main()
{
    foo::bar b;
    bar_cast<int>(b);
}
```

Comment: See my edit to explain why I thought that should/could cause ambiguity.

Comment: @einpoklum: well, you added *another* overload for `any_cast(any&)`. Your version is found using normal look-up, the `boost` version is found using argument dependent look-up. Neither one is better than the other. Obviously, that causes and ambiguity.

Comment: ^^ and the reason the const version is in the list is probably due to the compiler emitting a diagnostic before removing it from the list of candidates. Which is within its right.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the second part of your answer, but your comment gives me my answer.